# How to remove the word "ago"?

Tags: views, 8, theming, i18n-l10n, datetime

I use Drupal 8 in French and I have never managed to delete the word "ago" which means nothing in French.

How to remove the word "ago" in drupal 8?

When I created a duration since, drupal added "ago" at the end of the date.

[image]

Comment: Are you not able to set the translation for the word "ago" in `/admin/config/regional/translate` ?

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2639382

Comment: @NoSssweat No the word is not found and I want to delete it

Comment: Just FYI, be careful with using the very latest patch - see [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2639382#comment-12630246).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report and needs to handled int he issue queues